# Why are American states permitted to vote their own election laws?

Tags: united-states, election, us-state-laws

> Attorney General Merrick Garland announced Friday that the Department
> of Justice would be suing the state of Georgia over its recent voting
> rights changes. While the case is obviously directed at the Georgia
> lawmakers who passed the new restrictions and the governor who signed
> them into law, a broader challenge was also quietly being announced by
> the judge-turned-attorney general.

https://www.msnbc.com/opinion/why-doj-s-georgia-election-lawsuit-warning-shot-scotus-n1272436

Why are American states permitted to vote their own election laws? Wouldn't it make more sense to only allow the federal government to vote their own election laws and then force the states to abide by those rules? Why are the states given the right to do so? I believe this is not so in other countries, so there must be a particular reason for this.

Comment: American politics is permissive - anything is allowed unless it's forbidden.  It's a wrong question to ask why `x` is allowed since that is the default - it's more correct to ask why `x` is *not forbidden*.  Removing freedoms from people, companies, associations, cities, or states is something that requires a strong argument for intervention.  If working solutions exist that do not require removing freedoms and restricting activity then the American system is likely to leave the status-quo to be.

Comment: @Sayaman you must not be from around here.  The "federal government" is not the states' mother.  Every US State is independently sovereign, yet United by consent to be part of a shared republic for common defense, currency, highways and a few other things.  The purpose of that federal republic is not to control the states, but to serve them.  There are relatiely few federal-level contests on voting ballots here.  only every other year, and then only a couple federal contests on a ballot that might have 20-30 total contests.  Most issues are state or local.  So obviously states self-regulate.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Amendment 10

> The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the States respectively, or to the people.

Your question assumes a fundamental misconception of the nature of the USA.  The USA is a federal country. The States are generally free to pass laws as they see fit, that includes election laws, subject to the constitution.  The Federal government doesn't have the right to pass laws, except subject to the (fairly broad) conditions set down by the constitution. There is nothing in the constitution that allows the federal government to micromanage state elections of representatives and Senators.

Comment: That doesn’t sound right. Congress absolutely has the right to set laws to regulate state run elections if they choose to, the Voting Rights Act being one example. Not even the conservative majority in _Shelby_ disagreed with that. Can you clarify how this answer fits with examples like that?

Comment: I think James K is probably correct for this case. As stated in the wiki article,"Federal law originates with the Constitution, which gives Congress the power to enact statutes for certain limited purposes like regulating interstate commerce. " You can read it and find the rest of the "limited purposes", and to better understand the layers of the US laws. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_United_States#Federal_law

Comment: Article I, Section 8 of the U.S. Constitution specifies the “expressed” or “enumerated” powers of Congress. These specific powers form the basis of the American system of “federalism,” the division and sharing of powers between the central government and the state governments. The 17 enumerated powers of Congress can be read here https://www.thoughtco.com/constitution-article-i-section-8-3322343. None of them says about legislating "Voting or Election". Note that, according to the 10th amendment, all powers not granted to the U.S. Congress by Article I, Section 8 are left to the states.

Comment: Again, what about previous federal voting laws, or the principle “one man one vote” that was upheld IIRC federally? Does the federal government have zero influence on election practice?

Comment: @divibisan: It's really simple.  The Federal government can only intervene if a state enacts laws that (it can argue) are in violation of the US Constitution.  So if for instance a state enacted a law banning women from voting (or even making it more difficult for them than for men), that would be a violation of the 19th Amendment.  But saying all voters can vote by mail (which my state did in the last election) is the state's choice on how it wants to manage the election.

Comment: @jamesqf Thats clearly not true, as the Voting Rights Act established rules governing state elections and established federal oversight over any and all election decisions in the states listed in section 4. If you want to say the VRA is unconstitutional, a position that would make you even more of a radical than Scalia, say so, otherwise, how does your view square with that law?

Comment: Article I, section 4: "The Times, Places and Manner of holding Elections for Senators and Representatives, shall be prescribed in each State by the Legislature thereof; but the Congress may at any time by Law make or alter such Regulations". Art 2, Sec 1, 2nd para is about the same for electors for President

Comment: States' voting rules can be micromanaged -- that was "pre-clearance" in the Voting Rights Act. All new state voting rules had to be reviewed ahead of time in states that had a history of Jim Crow stuff.

Comment: @divibisan: The Voting Rights Act is only to insure that state elections comply with Constitutional provisions.

Comment: In addition to Article I, Section 4 quoted by Owen Reynolds, there is Article IV, Section 4: "The United States shall guarantee to every State in this Union a Republican Form of government".

Comment: Just as an extreme example of this: There is no US law against *murder*.  Of course murder is illegal in all 50 states and the territories, but not in the US as a whole.  If, say, North Dakota suddenly decided "Murder is legal here", they technically would be allowed to do that.  (There is obviously almost 0 chance of that happening, and it would likely be challenged in the Supreme Court even if it got through the state's legislature somehow, but currently there is nothing stopping them.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well, that's not quite true. There are [federal laws that define murders that are Federal offenses](https://www.shouselaw.com/ca/blog/murder/is-murder-a-federal-crime-7-ways-it-can-be/) and in your example, I assume Congress would probably expand them.

Comment: @divibisan I should've said no *general* law.  There are laws in a few specific cases, as you say.  But the vast majority of murders do not fall under any of those scenarios.

Comment: "that doesnt sound right" doesnt matter. the constitution is the supreme law of the land. we are not a democracy, we are a democratic republic. we use democracy inside of the law to decide open ended issues. states are autonomous, and create the federal government. the federal government does have authority (on whatever the constitution permits it) the constitution does provide express authority to the state legislatures on the elector process. the state legislatures have ultimate authority on electors. see article 2 section 1

Comment: The 10th Amendment is indecipherable because it doesn't distinguish which rights devolve to the States and which to the people. However, the Equal Justice clause of the 14th Amendment means that Congress gets to pass laws that set minimum standards for human rights, such as the Civil Rights Act and Voting Rights Act...i.e. the Federal government gets to say "these rights, at least, belong to the people, not the States".

Comment: @jamesqf That's untrue. It's already illegal to hold elections in a manner that's unconstitutional - congress passing another law wouldn't make it "double-illegal" or something. In reality, the VRA was itself unconstitutional since it would have required states to do things a certain way, which the federal government cannot regulate anyway due to the constitution.

Answer (score 37):

US election laws are a mainly left up to the individual states because the Constitution delegates broad election-related powers to the states. The federal government can create certain election laws that all states must adhere to, however these laws are generally limited to only specific protections outlined by the Constitution.

First off, according to the [Tenth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution), the federal government's powers are limited to only what is delegated to it by the Constitution:

> The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the States respectively, or to the people.

So, if the Constitution doesn't imply that the federal government can do something, then it's generally up to the state governments to handle it.

For election laws, the relevant powers are outlined in numerous articles and amendments. Here are few examples of powers granted to the individual states:

- [Article One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution) describes how representatives are simply chosen by 'the people' of each state, and senators were originally chosen by state legislatures:

> The House of Representatives shall be composed of Members chosen every second Year by the People of the several States, and the Electors in each State shall have the Qualifications requisite for Electors of the most numerous Branch of the State Legislature.

> The Senate of the United States shall be composed of two Senators from each State, chosen by the Legislature thereof, for six Years; and each Senator shall have one Vote.

- [Article Two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Two_of_the_United_States_Constitution) describes how presidential electors are appointed in whatever way a state legislature 'may direct':

> Each State shall appoint, in such Manner as the Legislature thereof may direct, a Number of Electors, equal to the whole Number of Senators and Representatives to which the State may be entitled in the Congress: but no Senator or Representative, or Person holding an Office of Trust or Profit under the United States, shall be appointed an Elector.

As you can see, originally the Constitution delegates broad powers to the states to handle federal elections. However, several articles and amendments define some protections that the state election laws needed to follow, and give the federal government the power to make laws to enforce them:

- As mentioned above, Article One gave states some broad powers to decide how members of Congress are elected, however [Section 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_1:_Time,_place,_and_manner_of_holding_elections) of Article One also gives Congress the power to make laws covering the 'time' or 'manner' of those congressional elections:

> The Times, Places and Manner of holding Elections for Senators and Representatives, shall be prescribed in each State by the Legislature thereof; but the Congress may at any time by Law make or alter such Regulations, except as to the Places of chusing Senators.

- The [Fifteenth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) prevents states from denying voting rights based on race:

> Section 1. The right of citizens of the United States to vote shall not be denied or abridged by the United States or by any State on account of race, color, or previous condition of servitude.
>
> Section 2. The Congress shall have power to enforce this article by appropriate legislation.

- The Seventeenth Amendment changed the way that senators were elected to match that of the representatives, thus taking some of the power away from the state legislatures:

> The Senate of the United States shall be composed of two Senators from each State, elected by the people thereof, for six years; and each Senator shall have one vote. The electors in each State shall have the qualifications requisite for electors of the most numerous branch of the State legislatures.

- The [Nineteenth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) prevents states from denying voting rights based on sex:

> The right of citizens of the United States to vote shall not be denied or abridged by the United States or by any State on account of sex.
>
> Congress shall have power to enforce this article by appropriate legislation.

- The [Twenty-fourth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-fourth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) prevents states from requiring voters to pay a [poll tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poll_taxes_in_the_United_States):

> Section 1. The right of citizens of the United States to vote in any primary or other election for President or Vice President, for electors for President or Vice President, or for Senator or Representative in Congress, shall not be denied or abridged by the United States or any State by reason of failure to pay any poll tax or other tax.
>
> Section 2. The Congress shall have power to enforce this article by appropriate legislation

- The [Twenty-sixth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-sixth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) prevents the states from denying voting rights based on age

> Section 1. The right of citizens of the United States, who are eighteen years of age or older, to vote shall not be denied or abridged by the United States or by any State on account of age.
>
> Section 2. The Congress shall have power to enforce this article by appropriate legislation.

There are some other articles/sections/amendments that cover election stuff, but you can see how the Constitution typically defines where the federal government can make election laws: it outlines a topic or protection that must be respected across the country, and explicitly gives Congress the power to make and enforce laws that guarantee those protections.

So, to sum it all up: election laws in the US are mainly handled by the individual states because the Constitution gives them broad powers to do so, either explicitly in various articles or more broadly through the Tenth Amendment. There are a few areas where the federal government can enforce election laws across all of the states, but these areas are fairly limited in scope so most of the power still rests in the hands of each state.

Comment: You omitted an important constitutional provision: Article I, Section 4, Clause 1: "The Times, Places and Manner of holding Elections for Senators and Representatives, shall be prescribed in each State by the Legislature thereof; but the Congress may at any time by Law make or alter such Regulations, except as to the Places of chusing Senators." This is only with respect to federal elections; the Congress cannot tell states how to "chuse" state representatives and state senators, subject to voting rights.

Comment: @Wastrel: Thanks, when I was going through and grabbing all of the citations I was just thinking about all of the civil rights amendments, I completely missed that section right in Article I. It's definitely one of the more important ones covering federal power, and I just added it to my answer.

Comment: "because the Constitution _gives_ them broad powers" --> Hmm, I thought it was not so much what the Constitution gives to the states as much as what was given by the states to the federal government and what states retained.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Agreed, the Constitution does not delegate those powers to the states, the states reserved them when the Constitution was adopted. The current wording in this answer promotes the confusion of non-Americans with regards to the federal system.

Answer (score 11):

Answers and comments about [article I,section 4](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/article-1/section-4/) of the US constitution, as well as the [tenth amendment](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/amendment-10/) are spot on for the implementation around how it works that states do this, but the other answers don’t mention an important point, in my view, around why:

The general idea of representatives holding federal office in the US is mostly based on the idea that the States themselves are the ones who nominate and even vote for (i.e.: electoral college) federal office holders. States elect the president, states send representatives and senators to the congress. Individual American citizens aren’t the ones appointing these federal office holders, at least not directly.

In general the constitution wasn’t as concerned with identifying the rights of individuals around government representation as it was around outlining how the states would still be power holders in the federal system.

When viewed in these terms it makes more sense that the states manage their own elections.

There are lots of, frankly valid, discussions within the US on wether individual representation is hampered by the state centric system in place, but knowing the system is mostly centered around the states is an important point when asking something about why US laws do something involving the Federal government.

Comment: Agreed. The United States are... well... a set of _states_ that are _united_. They're a federation of independent region states (more like the EU than like any country _within_ the EU, and it doesn't surprise us that individual EU countries each have their own election laws, and their own way of selecting who they want to be the executive head of the EU).

About the only times the federal government intervenes is when there's a case of discrimination by race/religion/disability/etc, since that makes it an "equal protection" issue, which _is_ the purview of the federal gov't.

Answer (score 9):

> *Why are American states permitted to vote their own election laws? Wouldn't it make more sense to only allow the federal government to vote their own election laws and then force the states to abide by those rules? Why are the states given the right to do so? I believe this is not so in other countries, so there must be a particular reason for this.*

At the time of the founding of the United States, the states already had election laws for their own legislatures and executive officers. In deciding who should make election laws for the election of Representatives, the Convention left it to the states, as explained in [Federalist 52](https://guides.loc.gov/federalist-papers/text-51-60#s-lg-box-wrapper-25493428) (with regard to the election of Representatives).

> FROM the more general inquiries pursued in the four last papers, I pass on to a more particular examination of the several parts of the government. I shall begin with the House of Representatives. The first view to be taken of this part of the government relates to the qualifications of the electors and the elected. Those of the former are to be the same with those of the electors of the most numerous branch of the State legislatures.
>
> The definition of the right of suffrage is very justly regarded as a fundamental article of republican government. It was incumbent on the convention, therefore, to define and establish this right in the Constitution. To have left it open for the occasional regulation of the Congress, would have been improper for the reason just mentioned.**<sup>1</sup>** To have submitted it to the legislative discretion of the States, would have been improper for the same reason; and for the additional reason that it would have rendered too dependent on the State governments that branch of the federal government which ought to be dependent on the people alone. **To have reduced the different qualifications in the different States to one uniform rule, would probably have been as dissatisfactory to some of the States as it would have been difficult to the convention. The provision made by the convention appears, therefore, to be the best that lay within their option.** [Emboldening added.]

**<sup>1</sup>** Explanatory note: To have left it to regulation by Congress would have violated republican form of government.

---

Later, the election of Senators and presidential electors followed from the same standards as the election of Representatives.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The Constitution specified *what was needed at the time of ratification*.  Under the Articles of Confederation, Congress had no power to make laws over the states, so the only means to make laws that would elect the first constitutional Congress was by the states themselves.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that people from outside (and some inside) the United States need to understand is, when the country was formed it wasn't from one large region splitting from Great Britain. It was thirteen separate colonies each with their own cultures that formed an alliance to gain independence. After the American Revolution the States barely worked together, and often not at all.  When the Articles of Confederation failed to maintain a unified country, the U.S. Constitution was created as a document that gave some federal authority to control things that should be centralized such war and international trade, but left everything else to the States, otherwise they wouldn't have agreed to it.